# HTML css linear-gradient not working as expected

Tags: html, css, html5-canvas, linear-gradients

I'm just working with linear-gradient in css, btw the generated gradient effect isn't same as the designs. I have never faced this problem in any Android, iOS, React Native or HTML5 canvas yet, but only on css.

```
.gradient {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right top, red, blue);
}
```

I have made a fiddle for showing the differences between css's `linear-gradient` and canvas's create `createLinearGradient`.
Please check this [fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/acuLnet5/8/).

[image: example]

The upper is css gradient and lower is canvas one.
As you can see the canvas's `createLinearGradient` working well as expected, but on the css the `same-color-line`(yellow line in above pic) isn't vertical of the gradient's direction, rather looks as the another `diagonal` of the element.
Is there any reason why is it in css?

Comment: This explains things pretty well: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient. It displays like this because you added the "top" value

Comment: @Sorix, really thanks, your link is so helpful to understand about the linear-gradient, btw I have to make the gradient as to top-right direction for any dynamic rectangle elements. Is there any solution of my case in css?

Comment: maybe use an angle instead of top or bottom. If I understand correctly, your gradient should always be at the same angle... like this: linear-gradient(45deg, red, blue);

Comment: updated my answer with an interactive Demo

Answer (score 2):

This is by design. You can read more about here: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-images-3/#linear-gradients.

> If the argument instead specifies a corner of the box such as `to top left`, **the gradient line must be angled such that it points into the same quadrant as the specified corner**, and is perpendicular to a line intersecting the two neighboring corners of the gradient box. This causes a color-stop at 50% to intersect the two neighboring corners.

Basically, when using such keywords you will have a kind of stretched gradient going from corners and you loss the perpendicular feature with the diagonal.

```css
.child {
  position:relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, red 50%, blue 0);
}
.child.alt {
  width:200px;
}

.child:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:linear-gradient(to top left,transparent calc(50% - 5px),green,transparent calc(50% + 5px) );
}
```

```html
this one is good because it's a square
<div class="child"></div>
but not this one
<div class="child alt"></div>
```

If you want to have the second output you need to use explicit angle and find the one that will make your gradient line the same as you diagonal line and for this you need to consider the angle equal to `arctang(width/height)`

In your case it will be `arctang(300/75) = arctang(4) = 75.69deg`. Since you are using JS you can easily do this calculation.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 75, 300, 0);
grd.addColorStop(0, "red");
grd.addColorStop(1, "blue");

ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 75);
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #6EE2F5;
}
.child {
  width: 300px;
  height: 75px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-image: linear-gradient(75.69deg, red, blue);
}
#canvas {
  width: 300px;
  height: 75px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div class="child"></div>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=75/>
</div>
```

Here is an interactive Demo

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

function update() {
 var H = $('[name=h]').val();
 var W = $('[name=w]').val();
 $('.child').css('height',H);
 $('.child').css('width',W);
 $('canvas').attr("width", W);
 $('canvas').attr("height", H);
 var angle = Math.atan(W/H) 
 $('.child').css("--a", (angle * 180 / Math.PI)+"deg");

 var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, H, W, 0);
 grd.addColorStop(0.4, "red");
 grd.addColorStop(0.6, "blue"); 
 ctx.fillStyle = grd;
 ctx.fillRect(0, 0, W, H);

}
$('input').change(update);
update();
```

```css
.child {
  border: 1px solid;
  background-image: linear-gradient(var(--a), red 40%, blue 60%);
}
#canvas {
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
W: <input type="number" name="w" step="1" value="300">
H: <input type="number" name="h" step="1" value="75">
<div class="child"></div>
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=75/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just replace `to right top` to `to right`. If you set it to `to right top` there is a certain degree applied to [`linear-gradient()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/linear-gradient) as it takes the bottom left as the starting point and extends up-to right top corner of the rectangle.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

var grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 75, 300, 0);
grd.addColorStop(0, "red");
grd.addColorStop(1, "blue");

ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 75);
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #6EE2F5;
}

.child {
  width: 300px;
  height: 75px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, blue);
}

#canvas {
  width: 300px;
  height: 75px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
  <canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=75/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however is there any exact solution of my requirement (right-top diagonal)? I exactly need that.

Comment: But why would you need to use that keyword while requiring an alternative result? Is there any hackathon you are playing with? :)

Comment: I'm using that as a component on react project, so the element's size isn't fixed, will be change dynamically and the gradient should be work for any of rectangle.

Comment: *as it takes the bottom left as the starting point and extends up-to right top corner of the rectangle.* --> this isn't true, if it was this case then the OP should have the correct result

Comment: @TemaniAfif Can you update the answer then? I had to take this as reference: https://prnt.sc/oyk1hb if MDN is wrong or I am, please correct both of us with an edit.

Comment: The MDN and you aren't wrong. My comment wasn't accurate but I was comparing with the Canvas gradient as the gradient line need to be perpendicular to the diagonal and if the starting point and end point are the corner it won't be the case ... well it's a bit tricky, will try to detail this in my answer

Comment: to illustrate what I was thinking about: https://jsfiddle.net/tLh3de59/1/ ... in the first example the gradient line is perpendicular to the diagonal and we have what the OP expect because it's a square ... now in the second example, we are stretching the first one which will break the logic the OP is looking for ... the third one is the good result because if we stretch we keep the same angle as the first.

Comment: Yes I can understand you. You had this in mine, didn't you? https://developer.mozilla.org/files/3537/linear-gradient.png

Comment: yes if you consider this from a geometry perspecitve ... see how the starting and ending point are outside BUT visually they have the same value of the corner since the line going from the corner and those point is perpendicular to the gradient line. So when using `to top right` the starting point/end point aren't the corner (what I was trying to say) but visually they have the same value (like described in the MDN and your answer)